# Using Lookup in Excel to populate column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to use the LOOKUP function to fill a "fault type" column based on what the "fault description" is. I'm currently using the formula
`=LOOKUP(E2, M3:N17)` which is returning a value from my look-up table, but it is incorrect. Here is a [screenshot of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5v4O.png) can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

For context, I'm using a spreadsheet to record IT helpdesk problems (I know a database would be more efficient, but I'm a student and the exercise requires me to use Excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `VLOOKUP` rather than `LOOKUP`. Change your formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$M$3:$N$17,2,0)
```

and copy it down. The '2' tells Excel to read the second column from your lookup table. The '0' tells Excel to perform an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer, you might want to lookup these 2 functions: `Index()` and `Match()` because these are faster than vlookup. Just google it